# MySQL Array with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, arrays

I have a MySQL Database setup like so:

```
id | username
-------------
1  | name1
2  | name2
3  | name3
```

But when I use this code in PHP, it only reads the first name. 
NOTE: I need it to read just the names. The id is there for something else.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT `username` FROM `black_list`");      
$blacklist = array();         
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $blacklist[] = $row;
    if(!in_array($name,$blacklist))
    {
          //User not protected
    } else {
          echo "User Protected";
    }
 }
```

If anyone could help me, that would be great. Thanks :)

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: can anybody tell me where is $name variable defined? I can't see it defined!

Comment: He probably didn't include it in his post, Aspiring Aqib

Comment: He would be getting undefined variable error otherwise :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $blacklist[] = $row['username'];
}

if(!in_array($name,$blacklist))
{
      echo "Coming Soon";
} else {
      echo "User Protected";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
if (!in_array($name, mysql_fetch_array($sql))) {
    echo "Coming Soon";
} else {
    echo "User Protected";
}
```

But you should actually be doing it at the database level. This takes advantage of database optimizations and doesn't need one to load an *entire table* into memory.

```
$query = mysql_query(sprintf(
    'SELECT 1 FROM `skype_bl` WHERE `username`="%s"',
    mysql_real_escape_string($name)
));

if (mysql_num_rows($query)) {
    // Username not available
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to compare if `$name` is in the blacklist array.  For that you have to first build your blacklist array and then compare `$name` to it.  In your code it is just comparing name to the current contents of the `$blacklist` array and not the whole array.

If you are iterating 1st row it will add value of the first row of the resultset to the `$blacklist` and compare `$name` just with that one element.  When it goes to second row it adds the value of the second row in the resultset to the array thus this time it will compare `$name` to two elements in array(the first two rows in resultset).  Also it will check `$name` in `$blacklist` for each iteration in the resultset.  I don't think you want this.  So we first build an array of blacklist and then just compare it once.

```
//building the $blacklist array
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $blacklist[] = $row['username'];
}

//Comparing $name with all elements of $blacklist which is now a full list
if(!in_array($name,$blacklist)){
      echo "Coming Soon";
}else{
      echo "User Protected";
}
```